# flush_rewrite_rules not working on plugin deactivation, invalid URLs not showing 404

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules

i'm just about to release a community plug-in and have a few last anoying issues.

First, whenever i visit a page that would not be valid for the plugin, www.mydomain.com/forms/tester it will take me to a different page. What should happen, is the plugin code try and use the path 'tester', find there is no such file, and then return a page not found error.

Second, i am using AskApache RewriteRules viewer plugin to see my rules, and can see that even though i have deactivated my plug-in, rewrite rules remain 'index.php?formid=$matches[1]'. I cant understand as i am flushing rewrite rules on plugin deactivation, and i know the function is being called. This gives the same affect as above, with incorrect URLs not going to 404 but instead going to other pages.

Is there anyway to fix this, so that if a wrong page is visited, 404 are thrown?

Code is currently hosted here: . http://www.unifiedmicrosystems.com/products-and-services/software-development/wordpress/jformer-for-wordpress/.

I am just waiting for wordpress.org access to upload the source there for general use. I have tried to copy a cut down version with relevant parts below.

Many thanks in advance,

Chris

```
class JFormerForWP
{
static $errors = false; /* for debugging */
static $pluginPath;  
static $pluginUrl;  

public static function makeFormFactory($id,$class)
{
    $classPath = self::$pluginPath . "/forms/{$class}.php";
    require_once $classPath; 
}

/* called each request */
public static function init()
{
    self::$pluginPath = dirname(__FILE__);  // Set Plugin Path  
    self::$pluginUrl = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/jformer-for-wp/'; // Set Plugin URL  

    self::addRewriteRules();
    add_filter( 'query_vars', array(__CLASS__, 'addQueryVars'));
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array(__CLASS__, 'formDisplay'));

    add_action('wp_print_styles', array(__CLASS__, 'styles'));
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', array(__CLASS__, 'scripts') );
    add_shortcode('jformer', array(__CLASS__, 'shortcodeHandler'));

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_jFormerForWp', array(__CLASS__, 'ajaxHandler'));
    add_action('wp_ajax_jFormerForWp', array(__CLASS__, 'ajaxHandler'));
    self::$errors = new WP_Error();
}

public static function ajaxHandler()
{   
    $formID = $_POST['jFormerId'];
    echo self::getForm($formID);
}

public static function shortcodeHandler($atts, $content)
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => '0',
    'class' => '',
    'text' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    // echo 'dumping shortcode values. content: ' . $content . ', id: ' . $id . ', class: ' . $class . '<br >';

    $options = self::getOptions();
    $permastructString = $options['url_string'];
}

public static function getOptions()
{
    $options = get_option('jformer_options',array('url_string' => 'forms'));
    return $options;
}

public static function addRewriteRules()
{
    $options = self::getOptions();
    add_rewrite_rule( $options['url_string'] . '/?([^/]*)','index.php?formid=$matches[1]', 'top' ); 
}

public static function addQueryVars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'formid';
    return $vars;
}

public static function formDisplay()
{
}

public static function activate() 
{
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5', '<'))
    {
        deactivate_plugins(basename(__FILE__));
    }

    self::addRewriteRules();
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
}

public static function deactivate()
{

    delete_option('jformer_options');
    //$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);  
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
}

public static function addAdminPage()
{
    add_options_page( 'jFormer', 'jFormer Plugin', 'manage_options', 'jFormerForWP', array( __CLASS__ , 'displayAdminPageHtml' ));
}

public static function adminInit()
{
    register_setting( 'jformer_options', 'jformer_options', array(__CLASS__,'validateOptions') );
    add_settings_section('jformer_main', 'jFormer Settings', array(__CLASS__,'sectionText'), 'jformer_main_options');
    add_settings_field('jformer_url_string', 'Rewrite String', array(__CLASS__,'displayUrlStringSetting'), 'jformer_main_options', 'jformer_main');
    add_action('admin_notices', array(__CLASS__,'displayAdminNotices'));  
}

public static function sectionText()
{
    echo '<p>Main description</p>';
}

public static function displayUrlStringSetting()
{
    $options = self::getOptions();
    echo "<input id='jformer_url_string' name='jformer_options[url_string]' size='40' type='text' value='{$options['url_string']}' />";
}

public static function validateOptions($input)
{
    $input['url_string'] = trim($input['url_string']);

    if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{1,}$/i', $input['url_string']))
    {
        add_settings_error('jFormerForWP', 'url_string_error', 'Invalid URL string, please fix ensure string consists of alphanumeric characters only and is at least 1 character long', 'error' );
    }
    else
    {
        // add_settings_error('jFormerForWP', 'url_string_updated', 'String updated', 'updated' );
        $validatedOptions['url_string'] = $input['url_string'];
    }

    return $validatedOptions;
}

public static function registerAdminSettings()
{
        register_setting('JFormerForWPSettings', 'JFormerForWPSettings_option1');

}

public static function displayAdminPageHtml()
{   
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>jFormer for WordPress Plugin Options</h2>
        Options relating to the Custom Plugin.
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php   
            settings_fields('jformer_options'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('jformer_main_options'); ?>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function showMessage($message, $msgclass = 'updated')
{  
    echo "<div id='message' class='$msgclass'>$message</div>";  
}  

public static function insertSettingsLink($links)
{
    $settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=JFormerForWP">'.__('Settings','JFormerForWP').'</a>'; 
     array_unshift( $links, $settings_link ); 
     return $links; 
}

public static function styles()
{       
    wp_enqueue_style('jformer', self::$pluginUrl. 'css/style.css');
}

public static function scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jformer', self::$pluginUrl . 'jFormer/jFormer.js',array('jquery'));
}
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('JFormerForWP','activate'));
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('JFormerForWP','deactivate'));
add_action('init', 'JFormerForWP::init');
add_action('admin_init', 'JFormerForWP::adminInit');
add_action('admin_menu', 'JFormerForWP::addAdminPage');
?>
```

Comment: did you ever solve this? i am looking at the same thing right now: flush rules on deactivation

Comment: no still the same issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `delete_option('rewrite_rules');` on deactivate? I came across the following when investigating this problem and it did the trick for me:

> Typically you register post types on init. Some time after that, you
>   get the deactivation action. A responsible plugin would remove its
>   rewrite rules by flushing. However, it can't undo the registration, so
>   the flush doesn't remove the plugin's rewrites.
>
> The hacky workaround I've used is to just delete the rewrite_rules
>   option on deactivation. They will be generated again when they are
>   needed, so the only noticeable effect is that the next site view may
>   take a bit longer.

Have a look at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14761#comment:12 for a discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

I got around this niggling issue with something like the following:

```
function my_plugin_deactivate() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  unset($wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules['my-rewrite-match']);
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Note that `'my-rewrite-match'` is the original string you passed into `add_rewrite_rule`, not the regex it is internally mapped to.

Comment: This approach worked for me, but using `extra_rules_top` instead of `non_wp_rules`. If in doubt about what to unset, try adding `exit(var_dump($wp_rewrite));` to the bottom of the deactivate function and look for your rules in the output.

Answer (score 0):

doing something similar.... creating a portfolio post type plugin and am stuck in the same place.  activation seems to be ok.  deactivation just redirects to the homepage.  what i'd like is for the URL to remain the same but to generate a 404, so you know it is a broken link.  i know it is unlikely that a portfolio post type would be deactivated, but well it just seems like due diligence.

about the only source i've found on the subject:

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/how-to-flush-permalink-rules-with-flush_rules

not quite doing it for me.  i've also tried:

```
update_option('rewrite_rules');
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

on deactivate, but it isn't quite right either.