# Properly flush rewrite rules on plugin activation

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I am working on a plugin which register a custom post type, using a custom rewrite structure, defined as follows:

```
  /**
   * create_ldp_type - LDP Resource post type creation and registration
   *
   * @return {type}  description
   */
  public function create_ldp_type() {
      register_post_type('ldp_resource',
          array(
              'labels'  => array(
                  'name'              => __('Resources', 'wpldp'),
                  'singular_name'     => __('Resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'all_items'         => __('All resources', 'wpldp'),
                  'add_new_item'      => __('Add a resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'edit_item'         => __('Edit a resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'new_item'          => __('New resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'view_item'         => __('See the resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'search_items'      => __('Search for a resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'not_found'         => __('No corresponding resource', 'wpldp'),
                  'not_found_in_trash'=> __('No corresponding resource in the trash', 'wpldp'),
                  'add_new'           => __('Add a resource', 'wpldp'),
              ),
              'description'           => __('LDP Resource', 'wpldp'),
              'public'                => true,
              'show_in_nav_menu'      => true,
              'show_in_menu'          => true,
              'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
              'supports'              => array('title'),
              'has_archive'           => true,
              'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'ldp/%ldp_container%'),
              'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-image-filter',
      ));
  }
```

I was previously flushing the rewrite rules on an `init` hook, and as it seems not to be a proper solution I decided to switch on using the `register_activation_hook` method. As I am using the object-oriented approach, all my hooks are wrapped and called from the object constructor:

```
  /**
   * Default Constructor
   **/
  public function __construct() {
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($this, 'wpldp_rewrite_flush' ) );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($this, 'wpldp_flush_rewrite_rules_on_deactivation' ) );

    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($this, 'generate_menu_item') );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($this, 'remove_menu_item' ) );

    // Entry point of the plugin
    add_action('init', array($this, 'wpldp_plugin_update'));
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'load_translations_file'));
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'create_ldp_type'));
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'add_poc_rewrite_rule'));

  }
```

The code for my `wpldp_rewrite_flush` method is the following:

```
 public function wpldp_rewrite_flush() {
    // Register post type to activate associated rewrite rules
    $this->create_ldp_type();
    $this->add_poc_rewrite_rule();

    // Flush rules to be certain of the possibility to access the new CPT
    flush_rewrite_rules( true );
 }
```

I made sure that this code is executed by doing some debugging. I have been reading a lot of posts which all gives this solution as the best one, but my issue is that my custom post types cannot be accessed (404 error).

The URLs I am trying to access are of type `http://localhost/wordpress/ldp/actor/benoit-alessandroni/`, `actor` being a custom taxonomy term (a `ldp_container`. Using a call to `flush_rewrite_rules()` right after my call to `register_post_type` in the `create_ldp_type` method is working just fine, but I know that's not ok.

So, do you see anything obvious which could explain the issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way: In my plugins, `register_activation_hook` always have a line like `delete_option('rewrite_rules');` when I'm creating custom post types. WordPress will properly rebuild them.

I've provided a detailed [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210126/best-way-to-flush-rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-type-in-a-mu-plugins-plugin/233914#233914)

Also another inspiring answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/flush-rewrite-rules-not-working-on-plugin-deactivation-invalid-urls-not-showing)

Comment: Testing right now. Will let you know.

Comment: Before or after the post type creation ? Doesn't seem to be enoug... Arg.

Comment: In theory, it should not matter, since the `rewrite_rules` option will be rebuilt on the next page request, but this is arguable. 
Are you sure the error is a flush one? I mean if you manually flush the permalinks from dashboard it will work?

Comment: Yes if I flush them manually it is fine. Really weird. I cannot get it to work programmatically :-(